# Adding method to a class from another class file

Tags: java, class

Is it possible to code this way in Java? I have an original java file name ClassA, but I didnt want to mess around too much in it. So i create another ClassB.java to input new method to be called in ClassA.java

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA implements XYZ{

        public ClassA() {

            Abc();
        }
    }
```

ClassB.java

```
    public class ClassB {

        public ClassB Abc{
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your question makes little sense to me. Please clarify. Why not extend ClassA if you want to use its methods directly? Either that or use composition to use its functionality.

Comment: `public class ClassB extends ClassA`...?

Comment: The whole picture is like this, ClassA.java is only calling the method in ClassB.java

Comment: Please read [this official tutorial on Java classes and objects.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish.  If you're worried about breaking the class, then writing unit tests will help mitigate regressions in logic.  If you want to claim that `ClassB` **is a** `ClassA`, then inheritance is acceptable.  Could you be more explicit about your intentions?  Right now, they don't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another things you can declare in the ClassA variable to access the methods and attribute in ClassB like this:

```
public ClassA() {
    ClassB classB = new ClassB();
    classB.Abc();
}
```

or

```
public ClassA() {
    new ClassB().Abc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ClassB to have ClassA functionality, you should enhance ClassB either through inheritance or through composition. For example:

Inheritance:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
  // now can use or override ClassA methods.
}
```

Composition:

```
public class ClassB {
  private ClassA classA = new ClassA();

  // now we can use classA instance throughout this class
}
```

As a general rule, I try to favor composition over inheritance. An example of composition is giving your class a Scanner or ArrayList object, and using the Scanner or ArrayList in the methods of the class. As you can see, it would make no sense to try to have your class extend either of these two entities except in very peculiar circumstances.

Otherwise your question is still quite unclear and if you're still having problems and need our help, you would do well to give concrete examples of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Though your code is totally unclear, I feel you want this

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{
super.Abc(); //calls parent class method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA
```

will get you to your point